# Using .each() to loop through checked checkboxes and .append data

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have a series of rows in a table each with different values (prices) and each row has a checkbox. This table is generated through a PHP loop.

```
echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10' id='booking-list'><tr>";
echo "<th>Booking ID</th><th>Customer ID</th><th>Start Date</th><th>Course Name</th><th>Amount Due</th><th>Date Payment Due</th><th>Add to basket</th></tr>";
$x = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $balance = $row['price'] - $row['deposit'];

    echo "<td>" .$row['booking_id']. "</td><td>" .$cust_id. "</td><td>" .$row['start_date']. "</td><td>" .$row['name']. "</td><td>" .$balance. "</td><td>" .$row['balance_due_date']. "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='" .$x. "' /></td></tr>";
    $x++;
}
echo "</tr><table>";
```

For every check box that is checked, I'd like to add (`.append`) the specific value (`$balance`) to a `form` input field. The appending part seems to be working but I'm not sure how to loop through each checked checkbox in jQuery to grab the value I need.

```
function(){
    $('#booking-list input:checkbox').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('<input />').attr({
                type: 'text',
            id: 'foo',
            name: 'bar',
        value: '<?php echo $balance; ?>'
        }).appendTo('#paypal-form form').text($(this).val());              
            } else {
                $('#paypal-form input:contains('+$(this).val()+')').remove();
            }
        });
```

Right now, I can only get the last `$balance` value generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `$balance` after the loop, that's why you are only getting the last value.

To use the value directly in the event handler, you would have to create a separate event handler for each checkbox inside the loop. Instead you can put the balance value in the data for the checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='' value='" .$x. "' data-balance='" .$balance. "' />
```

Then you can use it in the event handler:

```
value: $(this).data('balance')
```

Side note: Right now you only have code for adding inputs, so if someone checks something and then unchecks it, the input is still there.

Comment: I understand that currently I'm using $balance after the loop but I'd like to be able to use the $balance value associated with the specific rows and add that to the form input. Therefore there could be one, two or many depending on which checkboxes are checked. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: @ChrisJ: No, that doesn't make it any clearer. You are appending an input every time the user changes a checkbox. That specific checkbox only has one balance value. You can get the values from the checkboxes that are checked, but what would you want to do with those values?

Comment: sorry, the form that ois populated is then sent to PayPal for the customer to check out. I hadn't specified this. The input fields that will be appended will all be hidden so that in the end the user checks the rows they'd like to pay for and then continue to PayPal.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Yes, but with the code that I suggested you already have the balance value for each checkbox that gets checked. What would you want the other values for? You have already added an input for those.

Comment: For the PayPal form, I need to add more than one form field such as a name and item number. See http://www.peaknature.co.uk/payment-example.php.

Comment: For each checkbox that is ticked, I'd like to add some input fields to the form containing values from the corresponding row of the ticked checkbox.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Just put the separate values in separate data items in the checkbox, e.g. `data-name='" .$name. "' data-item='" .$item. '`, then create input elements for each one.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I'm still waiting to try it all out. I'll update you if I get it working/credit your answer etc.

Answer (score 10):

To select all checked checkboxes you can do:

```
  $('#booking-list input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      $(this).doSomething();//this is the checked checkbox
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it's because you're reusing the id for the input.   Have you tried putting the id of the input as the $cust_id?

syntax of each below:

```
$('selector').each(function (index, currentObject) {
   // index starts with 0
   $(currentObject).doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this code on checkbox `onClick` event too.

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {

});
```